# Is the iPhone/iPad delete "badge" available via the SDK?

Tags: iphone

I am creating an app with thumbnail views of my content.  I would like to put a "delete" badge in the upper left corner of each thumbnail like the one you see either when deleting apps from the iphone/ipad home screen.  It is typically a black circle with an 'X' inside.

Is this a badge or image file made available somehow through the SDK?

//Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but [here's one](http://www.noahw.me/syfiles/delete-button-icon.png). Enjoy.